# How to pass `this` as an argument in javascript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using javascript in my project.

I have on `HTML table <table id='idDocList'>` and I am doing `append` some html on this table as below code.
But I want to hide respective `<tr>` when user click on `Delete` anchor tag.

```
$("#idDocList").append("<tr><td>" + file.name + "</td><td>" + sz + "</td><td><a onclick=deleteDocument(this,'" + file.name + "')> Delete</a></td></tr>");
```

How can i do this using Jquery?

The following example does not work

```
function deleteDocument(CurAnchorTag, fileName) {
    $(CurAnchorTag).closest('tr').hide();
}
```

I don't want to use `ID` for `<a>` tag as I have many Documents.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Comment: You can pass `event` as a parameter instead of `this`. Then use `event.target` in your click handler function.

Comment: Also, `onclick='deleteDocument(this,\'" + file.name + "\')'`. Well, some people say I have OCD.

Comment: Here's a fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/p6m9yhkw/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a quick fix, you can use like this,

```
$(CurAnchorTag).closest('tr').hide();
```

Replaced `<tr>` with `tr`

You can remove the inline function call with jquery like this way,

```
$("#idDocList").on("click", "td a", function() {
    $(this).closest("tr").hide();
    var filename = $(this).closest("td").prev().text();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to change your code to:

```
var newRow = $("<tr><td>" + file.name + "</td><td>" + sz + "</td><td><a href='#'> Delete</a></td></tr>").appendTo("#idDocList");
newRow.find( 'a' ).click( function( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $( this ).closest('<tr>').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just use

```
$(".delete_link").click(function(){$(this).closest('tr').hide();}
```

Jquery will use the this of which ever element called it. There will be no need for the onclick on the html file.

Comment: Will not work if the function is called from `onclick` attribute

Answer (score 0):

You would better use event delegation and get rid of inline onclick handlers all together:

```
$('#idDocList').on('click', '.btn-delete', function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').hide();
    // read filename: $(this).data('filename')
});
```

And use it with HTML (the sting you append):

```
"<tr><td>" + file.name + "</td><td>" + sz + "</td><td><a class="btn-delete" data-filename='" + file.name + "'>Delete</a></td></tr>"
```

Note the part:

```
<a class="btn-delete" data-filename="filename">Delete</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You recommend you to use event for a class using the jquery

```
$("#idDocList").append("<tr><td>" + file.name + "</td><td>" + sz + "</td><td><a class='delete_link'> Delete</a></td></tr>");
```

The code below will add the event and need to execute always after add a "tr", unless you use a delegate to this

```
$(".delete_link").click(function(){ $(this).closest("tr").hide() });
```

If you don't want to use a class you can use this

```
$("#idDocList td > a").click(function(){ $(this).closest("tr").hide() });
```